# Can't find GitHub invitation to join repo?

Tags: github

I've been invited to join a GitHub repo. I've seen on the team leads computer that I definitely have been invited. However I haven't received an email and I can't see any notifications when I log into GitHub. How can I find my invite and join the repo?

Comment: Check the all notifications: https://github.com/notifications?all=1 Also, contact GitHub staff, instead of asking on [so].

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had an invitation from 6 hours ago but the only way I was able to view it was by going directly to the project page.

https://github.com/project/

Here a screenshot:
[image: GitHub Screenshot]

Comment: A small nitpick on terminology: I believe you're referring to the "organization page", not a project page (extra confusing since projects are a new thing introduced recently in github).

I've also seen that an invitation for a organization (and a team within the organization) is shown on the organization page.

Answer (score 143):

If you got invited to join a GitHub organization (or a team within a organization), then you can see this invite on the following link:

- https://github.com/orgs/PUT_ORGANIZATION_NAME_HERE/invitation

If you want to accept a repository invite, then you can use this schema:

- https://github.com/PUT_ORGANIZATION_NAME_HERE/PUT_REPOSITORY_NAME_HERE/invitations

Comment: Absolutely amazing, we were unable to complete my invitation for days, they resent me the invitation multiple times, this answer is the one that finally helped me.

Comment: Nowadays, you can just go to "Notifications" and you'll find it there.

Comment: wow github really sucks at this. talking about one of the most visited site by programmer

Comment: @Abel I don't seem to receive invitations in my "Notifications" page.

Comment: October 2021, weird that this has not yet been fixed

Comment: 2024, still having this issue 

Answer (score 22):

You can get the repository link from the person who invited you and just add `/invitations` at the end of that URL.

e.g.

https://github.com/<UserName>/<RepositoryName>/invitations

Make sure you are already logged in to the GitHub account for which invitation was sent.

Comment: Same goes for joining an organization. I couldn't find the invite in my email but went to https://github.com/orgs/<OrganizationName>/invitation and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 7):

Accept is through the email or a project page.

Comment: +1 Does not appear on your own repository list until you accept the email invitation, then reload your own GitHub repository list.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to add a collaborator who had kept his e-mail private.  That meant that he could not receive the invitation either directly via e-mail or by checking his notifications on Github.

Also, the link method suggested above:
https://github.com/PUT_ORGANIZATION_NAME_HERE/PUT_REPOSITORY_NAME_HERE/invitations

Gave my collaborator a 404 error. Once they made his e-mail public, all of the above methods worked.

Worth knowing. Tough on newbies!

Answer (score 1):

The same issue was resolved by emailing the invitation, not by the GitHub user account.

So you type out the whole email address of the user in the member invite input field and don't select the user but just invite using the email.

This resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the repo page , if you know the name, by typing it in the url after github.com.
Eg. github.com/developersgithubname/projectname. Once there, you can accept or deny the request.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly deleted the email sent to me, but then I formatted the URL like so and this worked for me:

`https://github.com/orgs/<REPOSITORY_NAME>/invitation`

Answer (score -1):

If you don't get the email right away just keep unlinking your account on the unreal website dashboard in accounts, and then relinking again. I had to do it no more than 4 times in an hour, and it worked, and I got the email with the forth attempt. I joined and can see the repo, whereas before it was just 404