# Github Problem : not invited to repository

Tags: github, repo

I got some troubles with github.
My coworker invited me to the repo but I can't see that anywhere.
Is there any problem like this??

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question &  this can help you

If you got invited to join a GitHub organization (or a team within an organization), then you can see this invite on the following link:

https://github.com/orgs/PUT_ORGANIZATION_NAME_HERE/invitation
If you want to accept a repository invite, then you can use this schema:

https://github.com/PUT_ORGANIZATION_NAME_HERE/PUT_REPOSITORY_NAME_HERE/invitations

Source question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020327/cant-find-github-invitation-to-join-repo)

Or

use this link below to see if there is any invitation: https://github.com/project/

Comment: Oh I got now! thank you a lot.